# Apache: Websocket returning HTTP 200 over proxy when needing HTTP 101

Tags: javascript, apache, websocket, proxy

I'm attempting to run https://github.com/dynastic/place through an Apache proxy. Everything works except a websocket returning HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 101, which causes errors in both Chrome and Firefox. How can I rectify this problem?

The Apache 2.4 proxy is running through a FreeNAS jail [192.168.0.2] and the repo (Place) is running on a Debian VM [192.168.0.3]. The proxy begins at subdomain.domain.com and routes to 192.168.0.3:3000. Everything works perfectly except a websocket that returns HTTP 101 when connecting to http://192.168.0.3:3000 but returns an HTTP 200 when connecting through https://subdomain.domain.com.

I have config files all over the place that I can provide if needed, but here is the main config file. SSL configuration is defined in other files and SSL does not seem to be the problem as I have tried on HTTP.

`sites-enabled/place.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName subdomain.domain.com

ErrorLog /path/to/error.log
CustomLog /path/to/access.log combined

SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Location />
        ProxyPass http://192.168.0.3:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.0.3:3000/
</Location>
RequestHeader set Connection "Upgrade"

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* wss://192.168.0.3:3000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]



</VirtualHost>
```

In the Readme.md on the Place GitHub repo, it shows an Nginx repository which in theory returns the correct HTTP 101 code (I tested locally). Apache incorrectly returns an HTTP 200 code. I currently use Apache for other services on the server so sticking with that would be nice but at this point I may have to look for other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem simply by switching to Nginx and using the example code in the repository. If anyone is in this exact situation I recommend not going through the toil I did and just switch if my situation is similar to yours.